# Android Studio generating signed apk modules.xml not found

Tags: android, android-studio

I am trying to generate a signed application in Android Studio and I am getting the following error. The .idea folder is missing the modules.xml file, but it seems to me this should be auto-generated by Android Studio. I am new to Android Studio, why am I missing .idea/modules.xml file? And how do I generate it?

```
Internal error: (java.io.FileNotFoundException) /home/will/git/mtdapp/.idea/modules.xml         (No such file or directory)
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/will/git/mtdapp/.idea/modules.xml (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:140)
at com.intellij.openapi.util.JDOMUtil.loadDocument(JDOMUtil.java:340)
at org.jetbrains.jps.model.serialization.JpsLoaderBase.loadRootElement(JpsLoaderBase.java:69)
at org.jetbrains.jps.model.serialization.JpsLoaderBase.loadRootElement(JpsLoaderBase.java:40)
at org.jetbrains.jps.model.serialization.JpsProjectLoader.loadFromDirectory(JpsProjectLoader.java:123)
at org.jetbrains.jps.model.serialization.JpsProjectLoader.loadProject(JpsProjectLoader.java:99)
at org.jetbrains.jps.model.serialization.impl.JpsSerializationManagerImpl.loadModel(JpsSerializationManagerImpl.java:41)
at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.JpsModelLoaderImpl.loadModel(JpsModelLoaderImpl.java:45)
at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildRunner.load(BuildRunner.java:71)
at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.runBuild(BuildSession.java:198)
at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.run(BuildSession.java:113)
at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain$MyMessageHandler$1.run(BuildMain.java:133)
at org.jetbrains.jps.service.impl.SharedThreadPoolImpl$1.run(SharedThreadPoolImpl.java:41)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1146)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:701)
```

Comment: Check the file at path mentioned in the logs. This file is generated automatically for you by ide. Make sure you have read write access on directory and let me know.

Comment: I do have read/write permissions. The contents of my .idea folder are (copyright  libraries  misc.xml  scopes  workspace.xml), missing the modules.xml file. I'm not sure why Android Studio hasn't auto-generated this file, or how I can do it myself.

Comment: Close studio, delete .iml and .idea directory :reimport project.

Comment: Is your problem got resolved ?

Comment: let me include in answer then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Close Android Studio, delete .iml and .idea directory and Re-import project.

Comment: I had added some modules from the command line, not using Android Studio, so Android studio never triggered the creation of the modules.xml file. This fix is what I needed, thank you!